# Creating a CI pipeline for .net containerized applications

Tags: .net, git, jenkins, docker, continuous-integration

**My Goal**

As the title says, I am trying to put together a CI (Continuous Integration) pipeline for a raft of .NET services which are going to be run in a dockerized environment in Linux. The developers at my organisation use C#, and VSO/TFS currently, so we are attempting to migrate to a Linux platform while retaining the tooling/skill-set of our current team.

I have seen a lot of posts on various forums, but have been unable to find anything that addresses my specific need - so if this has been answered before - I would very much appreciate a link!

So far, I have done the following to try to prove what I can do:

1. Created a C# project with a unit test.
2. Checked the project into source control (TFS online)
3. Running Jenkins on a linux box
4. Set up Jenkins to listen for pushes into source control.
5. When new code detected, a build is kicked off on a Jenkins node (which is a Windows machine) using MSBuild plug-in
6. If build completes without errors, use MSTest plug-in to run all the unit tests associated to the C# project.

All the above seems to work just fine - it's the next bit that I am struggling with.

**What I want to do**
Now that I have a build completed and tested in code, I want to be able to do the following (at a high level):

1. Move source code from the Jenkins windows node to a Jenkins Linux node
2. Build a docker container on the Linux node
3. Push the docker container into a repository

**What I have tried**
I am using a freestyle project in Jenkins to orchestrate the above. (Not sure if this is the right choice - but seems to do the pull/build/test without breaking a sweat.)

I figured that in order to get the code from the Windows node to the Linux node, I would need to push into a GIT repository. My requirement is that this is a local GIT, but if that is not possible, I am open to using a private GIT online.

I tried setting up a local Gogs-GIT repository, but Jenkins doesn't speak the same language as it. In any case - I haven't been able to figure out how to use any of the Jenkins plug-ins to push code as a post build event from my Windows node into a different source control environment than where it came from in the first place.

I am now thinking that maybe I need to execute some sort of custom script (maybe a batch script on the Windows node) to do a push into GIT and then have a separate Jenkins job that listens for pushes to the GIT repository to start the Linux process.

I am pretty new to both Linux and Jenkins, so any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depending on what version of TFS you are using, it supports git repositories, may be worth looking into. Microsoft also provides a [command line tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx) to access code stored in TFS, which should work around the first of your goals.

Comment: There is also this article on MSDN on [Building Docker Images for .NET Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/building-net-docker-images) that may be worth checking out if you haven't yet.